# SSL configuration with wildfly 25

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wildfly, wildfly-25

I am trying to configure  SSL certificate with wildfly 25. I have modified standalone.xml file like below :

```
 <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
                 <server-identities>
                     <ssl>
                       <keystore path="certificate.jks" relative-to="/tools/wildfly/standalone/configuration" keystore-password="password" />
                     </ssl>
                 </server-identities>
         </security-realm>
 </security-realms>


<server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm"  socket-binding="https" ssl-context="applicationSSC" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <http-invoker http-authentication-factory="application-http-authentication"/>
                </host>
            </server>
```

I am getting below error:

```
</security-realms>
 <security-realms>
 <security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
 ^^^^ 'security-realm' isn't an allowed element here

            Did you mean 'identity-realm'?
```

I tried to change tag to `<identity-realm>` too..but getting same error for that tag too. Can someone help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to move to elytron as security realms are now removed